# ManifestError : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

i Have a problem.
This source code : https://github.com/Toolwiz/ToolWizAppLock/
there is a notification error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

[image: error in manifest]

I've added and read other posts to solve similar problems, but it does not work. I use android studio version 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cleanwiz.applock"
    android:versionCode="18"
    android:versionName="2.10" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.AppLockApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- android:noHistory="true" -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.LockMainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <!-- <intent-filter> -->
            <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> -->


            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
            <!-- </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.GuideActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.StepActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.GestureCreateActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.GestureUnlockActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Splash" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.GestureCheckActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.AppLockActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.TimeLockMgrActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.TimeLockEditActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.AppSettingActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.SettingActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.SettingExActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.FeedbackActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.SecretConfig"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.NormalQAActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.LookMyPrivateActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.WifiLockMgrActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.WifiLockEditActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.UserUnlockActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.TipsLockActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.ChooseAppsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.UserHelpActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.NumberCreateActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.NumberCheckActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.NumberUnlockActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.SecretCheckActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.ui.activity.AppsLinkActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.PicHideActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.PicPreViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.FileHideActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.FilePreViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.AudioHideActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.AudioPreViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.VideoHideActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.VideoPreViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".files.activity.PhotoPreViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <!-- android:process=":LockService" -->
        <service
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.LockService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":LockService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.LockService" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" />
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.UpdateService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.AppLockBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.LockReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
                <action android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.CHECK_LOCK" />

                <component android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.UpdateService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- <receiver -->
        <!-- android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.DeviceAdminSample" -->
        <!-- android:description="@string/app_name" -->
        <!-- android:label="@string/app_name" -->
        <!-- android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" > -->
        <!-- <meta-data -->
        <!-- android:name="android.app.device_admin" -->
        <!-- android:resource="@xml/device_admin" /> -->
        <!-- <intent-filter> -->
        <!-- <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" /> -->
        <!-- </intent-filter> -->
        <!-- </receiver> -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.cleanwiz.applock.service.DeviceMyReceiver"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you :D

Comment: this code copy from github and past in your `manifist.xml`?

Comment: this dude, https://github.com/Toolwiz/ToolWizAppLock/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: same code u put in your `manifest.xml`?

Comment: yes same, im import from eclipse to android studio

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FNJO.jpg error

Comment: do u know `manifest.xml` create when u create a `activity` so your `MainActivity.java` or  `SplashActivity.java` file not same then it's problem occurred

Comment: http://prntscr.com/iiph62

Comment: but bring up 1 code that is always error

Comment: it seems there is only 1 single manifest. AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: can u try this after removing this error line ?

Comment: no, another error appears.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/iipka4

Comment: i'll try in my android studio same error occurred so u removed `<intent-filter android:priority="1000"/>` this line in `manifest.xml` all this line remove

Comment: can you send, screenshot. I have difficulty programming, because I am still in learning.

Comment: wait i'll put screenshot as a answer

Comment: i hope :D to fix thx problem :D

Answer (score 0):

**When i add this line `<intent-filter android:priority="1000"/>` in `manifest.xml` then show the `error` like :**

[image]

**When I remove this line `<intent-filter android:priority="1000"/>` then remove the `error` like :**

[image]

**So you remove this line from your `manifest.xml`** not one but all

Comment: i hope it's help for u